# Why is my PHP printing ADODB lines?

Tags: php

I am moving some php/adodb pages from my Ubuntu 12 to my Ubuntu 14 VM.  I believe I installed all the packages,

```
apt-get -y install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
apt-get -y install postgresql php5-pgsql php5-adodb libphp-adodb
```

but I am getting strange results.  My index.php code starts like this.

```
require "./main.inc";
require "./util.php";

$conn = ADONewConnection($dbtype);
$conn->PConnect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$step=1;

if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
        $step=2;
}

if ($step == 2)    #verify logon
{
```

When I open the browser and look at the page, I see this code partially being echoed. The first line in the browser shows this, plus more.

```
PConnect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname); $step=1; if (isset($_POST["submit"])) { $step=2; } if ($step == 2) #verify logon {
```

The php seems to be fine as the html parts are displayed properly, but the adodb calls are just getting printed instead of run.  It seems whatever code I have after the 'ADONewConnection' line just gets printed out.

I checked phpinfo and the module for adodb is listed.  I'm just not sure if I missed a setup step somewhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, to be more specific, everything after the first '$conn->' get printed.

Comment: So you are mixing PHP and HTML code, can you post more code? This seems to be a very shortened part. And also, is your file extension `.php`? Are you enclosing the PHP code between `<?php` and `?>`?

Comment: OK, this is weird.  It doesn't seem to be adodb related. The first time it gets to a '->', it prints the code. @EricMartinez, this code is correct.  I just moved the files from a working VM to this one.  I didn't make any code changes.

Comment: Because that's the first place where the tag is closed. Check the source on the browser and you'll see all the code. Server not running it as PHP  at all.

Comment: Check this thread and see if those steps help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EricMartinez for pointing to the other post, specifically point #5.  It was the following line in the php.ini that needed to be turned on.

```
short_open_tag = On
```

I should probably update all the old code to use the long tag, but enabling this got my pages back up.

Thanks.